# Receiving "Highcharts is not defined" error when using maps (Highmaps / Highcharts)

Tags: meteor, highcharts, highmaps

I've used Highcharts quite a bit and the charts work great, but I've been stuck trying to make Highmaps work for quite a while now.

I believe I have everything setup correctly with my test map that I'm trying to make work because it works correctly in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7oh56nk/).

The error I'm receiving in my browser console is this:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined at
>   https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world-highres.js:1:1 (anonymous function) @ world-highres.js:1"

The first part of [world-highres.js](https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world-highres.js) is:  `Highcharts.maps["custom/world-highres"] = { ...`

Does anyone know why Highcharts would be coming back as undefined here?

I'm using Meteor 1.3.5.1 and I have Highcharts 5.0.4 installed through NPM.

Here's how I currently have things setup:

**exampleTemplate.js**

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
require('highcharts/modules/map')(Highcharts);

Template.exampleTemplate.onRendered(function() {

  // Example data
  var mymapdata = [
    {
     key: "US",
     value: 198812
    },
    {
     key: "GB",
     value: 52894
    },
    {
     key: "CA",
     value: 35572
    }
  ];

  // Initiate
  Highcharts.mapChart('country-map-container', {
        title: {
            text: 'Highmaps Example'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Example'
        },
        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true,
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        },
        colorAxis: {
            min: 0
        },

        series: [{
            data: mymapdata,
            mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world-highres'],
            joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'key'],
            name: 'Random data',
            states: {
                hover: {
                    color: '#a4edba'
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
            }
        }]
  });

});
```

**exampleTemplate.html**

```
<template name="exampleTemplate">
  <div id="country-map-container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
</template>
```

**Head tag:**

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world-highres.js"></script>
</head>
```

Here's what it looks like with the code above:

[image: screenshot]

I've tried a lot of different things and spent a ton of time on this but nothing I've tried seems to make it work... Any help with this would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: I think you need this in your `<head>` too: `<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>`. Place it before the other script.

Comment: @Khang thank you for the reply. I've given that a try but unfortunately it just gives me [Error #16](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/16) - "Highcharts already defined in the page"

Comment: It is undefined because highcharts is not defined in the global namespace when bundled using imports and script is evaluated before the meteor bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your order is as follows,

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world-highres.js"></script>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/8ufz8u8z/)**